# Erlang Code Replacement

Tags: compiler-construction, erlang

I've created a simple module:

```
-module(check). 
-export([check/0]). 
check() ->
    Val = 1,
    io:format("Value = ~p~n",[Val]).
```

Code compiled with `erlc`. Now let's run Erlang:

```
Erlang R14B (erts-5.8.1) [source] [smp:4:4] [rq:4] [async-threads:0] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V5.8.1  (abort with ^G)
1> check:check().
Value = 1
ok
```

If I modify the code, change Val to 2, and compile with `erlc`, I would expect that `check:check` will return 2, but this is not the case:

```
2> check:check().
Value = 1
ok
```

We get the same result. Even if I restart the shell.

How could I force Erlang to reload module without killing the Virtual Machine?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After you recompile your module, just run, from the shell:

```
> l(check).
```

That will reload the new module and you will be ready to go.

Answer (score 2):

If you compiled the module ouside of the shell, you can reload it with:

```
> l(check).
```

If you want to both compile and reload you can do:

```
> c(check).
```